# Map a key value pair of the following Data?

Tags: java, collections, jxl

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0RRx.png)

I have the following excel Sheet and i want to bind it to a Map of key value pair.(Using JXl to parse data)
I want the data Structure to be like

```
Map<String,Map<String, List<String>>> map
```

where the key will be the Stage Request Set and then we have a map of stage req and stage seq.

i have been able to do the Map inside of the map i:e `Map<String, List<String>>`part

How to add the map to a map where it will be the value of a certain key.

```
              for(int i = 3;i<sheet.getRows();i++){               
                         if(!sheet.getCell(2,i).getContents().isEmpty()){
                             lastUpdated = sheet.getCell(2,i).getContents();                           
                         }

                         if (!sheet.getCell(3,i).getContents().isEmpty()) {
                             String content = sheet.getCell(3,i).getContents();
                             if (map.containsKey(lastUpdated)) {
                                 map.get(lastUpdated).add(content);
                             } else {
                                 ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                                 temp.add(content);
                                 map.put(lastUpdated, temp);
                             }
                         }

                     }
```

This will give us the whole stage req and stage seq in a Map which contains all the values of stage and its seq in a key value pair.

Now how to bind this map to Stage request Set name Key .

New to Java and collections please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe below is what you need. If it does not suffice, please share the complete excel sheet as a file via any cloud storage and your complete source code.

```
        Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 3;i<sheet.getRows();i++){
            if(!sheet.getCell(2,i).getContents().isEmpty()){
                lastUpdated = sheet.getCell(2,i).getContents();
            }

            if (!sheet.getCell(3,i).getContents().isEmpty()) {
                String content = sheet.getCell(3,i).getContents();
                if(!map.containsKey(lastUpdated)){
                    map.put(lastUpdated, new HashMap<>());
                }
                if(!map.get(lastUpdated).containsKey(content)){
                    Map<String, List<String>> rowMap = map.get(lastUpdated);
                    rowMap.put(content, new ArrayList<>());
                    map.put(lastUpdated, rowMap);
                }
                for(Cell c : Arrays.copyOfRange(sheet.getRow(i), 4, sheet.getRow(i).length)){
                    if(CellType.EMPTY != c.getType()){
                        map.get(lastUpdated).get(content).add(c.getContents());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Pavan Thanks , I have Updated the Sample Excel sheet i as the reason i was using  Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map u see the excel sheet sample the data in the row of  stage program has multiple values so i used a list in order to save those to.